# Stop sliding when play Vimeo or Youtube video in the slider

Tags: jquery, video, youtube, slider

Which the best way to have a script that I can stop the slider slide when I play Vimeo or Youtube video in the slider?

very much appreciated with you all help.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#gdl-custom-slider ul').cycle({ 
    before:     before_transition,
    after:      after_transition,
    fx:         'fade',
    pager:      '#custom-slider-nav',

    speed:      CUSTOM.speed, 
    timeout:    CUSTOM.timeout 
});



function before_transition(curr, next, opts, fwd){
    jQuery(next).find('.custom-slider-title').css({'top':'15px','opacity':'0'});
    jQuery(next).find('.custom-slider-caption').css({'top':'15px','opacity':'0'});
}

function after_transition(curr, next, opts, fwd){
    jQuery(this).find('.custom-slider-title').delay(100).animate({'top':'0px','opacity':'1'}, 200);
    jQuery(this).find('.custom-slider-caption').delay(400).animate({'top':'0px','opacity':'1'}, 200);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Vimeo and Youtube player APIs.

### Vimeo

To turn the API on, add `api=1` to the URL of the `iframe`, like this:

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID?api=1
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bdougherty/UTt2K/light/)

More information [**here**](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api).

---

### Youtube

To turn the API on, add `?version=3&enablejsapi=1` to the iframe url.

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&enablejsapi=1
```

[**DEMO**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)

See more information on the [**documentation pages**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#onYouTubePlayerReady).

---

When clicking "Start" button you will stop the slider, and when you will click the "Start" button you will start the slider.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.... i still not really understand.. perhaps can show me some example how to make it work?

Comment: @Jikey Please create a JSFiddle with your html, CSS and javascript.