# How to stop slider and play video then resume

Tags: jquery, html, css, video, bxslider

**INFO**

I'm using [bxslider.js](http://bxslider.com/) which I love, but it has an issue with playing video. Author feels it is not an issue and pointed me here.

**PROBLEM**

It shows video slide and plays the video, but the slider keeps sliding and you can hear it in the background while the slider goes through each consecutive slide. User experience isn't very friendly.

**QUESTION**

This is the desired sequence:
(1) show video slide
(2) user clicks play and video plays
(3) slider is paused so user can view the video
(4a) video finishes and slider resumes automatically -OR-
(4b) user pauses video and slider resumes automatically -OR-
(4c) user clicks next/previous slide button controls, video pauses, and slider resumes. User can un-pause the video when it shows up in the slider rotation.

Are 4a, 4b, and 4c possible or do I need to find a better slider?

**IMPORTANT:** I do **NOT** want to rely on static next/prev buttons - I want the slider to run automatically.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/9qmsdo7g/)**

---

**HTML**

```
<section id="container">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
            <div class="text">SLIDE 1</div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff" /></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="text">SLIDE 2</div>
            <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/17914974" width="600" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="text">SLIDE 3</div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x300/333/fff" /></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**JS**

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal', //horizontal vertical fade
    speed: 750, //transition duration
    infiniteLoop: true,
    captions: false,
    video: true,
    responsive: true,
    pager: true,
    pagerType: 'full', //full or short
    controls: true,
    auto: true,
    pause: 4000,
    autostart: true,
    autoHover: true,
    autoDelay: 2500,
    adaptiveHeight: false,
    onSliderLoad: function(){
        $("#container").css("visibility", "visible").hide().fadeIn(1000);
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```css
 #container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 600px;
   height: 300px;
   text-align: center;
   visibility: hidden;
   padding: 0 0 20px 0;
 }
 .text {
   width: 20%;
   color: #F00;
   z-index: 99999;
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 /* override css*/
 .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
   -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
   box-shadow: none !important;
   border: none !important;
 }
 .bx-controls-direction a {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 }
 .bx-wrapper:hover .bx-controls-direction a {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the direct `video` tag and not to embed it in an iframe. I don't know if you need Vimeo Pro for this.
[Vimeo video not working with HTML5 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426410/vimeo-video-not-working-with-html5-tag)

[Stop sliding when play Vimeo or Youtube video in the slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133994/stop-sliding-when-play-vimeo-or-youtube-video-in-the-slider)

Or you could use this: http://johndyer.name/html5-video-wrapper-for-youtube-and-vimeo-api-mediaelement-js/

And then change the script:

```
media.addEventListener('play', function() {
 //Put the script here to pause the slider
}, false);
```

Comment: That was just the example video from the dev's github. YouTube will be used. Apart from that, I don't believe the video is the problem - it's how the plugin code is reacting to how there is a video in the slide. It doesn't know what to do so it keeps rotating slides through.

Comment: The slider needs to "communicate" with the video or its player. So that one of them can react if something happens. Like you are saying: "user clicks play and video plays" which should send a "signal" telling the slider it should pause. If the video is in an iframe this "communication" is though.

Comment: I get your point, but the problem is that the slider, while advertised as able to play video, does not have any functionality to communicate with the video playing. It simply shows that there is a video slide and nothing else. So basically it's an animated slide. It wasn't coded to allow any interaction between the slider and the video. This is what I want to do if possible...so I'd need code to provide that "communication" as it doesn't exist. Or scrap it and find a new slider :/